# Deserialize multiple JSON arrays into separate C# datasets/datatables using JSON.net (newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, serialization, datatable, dataset, json.net

Im trying for hours now to get the following two JSON arrays (namely clients and dossiers) into two **separate** datasets/datatables using Newtonsoft JSON.net in C#:

```
{
   "status": "OK",
   "clients": [
    {
        "ClientID": "123456",
        "Fullname": "John Doe",
        "Inactive": false
    },
    {
        "ClientID": "234567",
        "Fullname": "James Smith",
        "Inactive": false
    }
   ],
   "dossiers": [
    {
        "CreateDate": "03.06.2013",
        "DossierName": "JD20130603"
    },
    {
        "CreateDate": "04.06.2013",
        "DossierName": "JS20130604"
    }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance...

EDIT: I would like to avoid the whole Class thing if possible.

EDIT 2: So far Ive tried the following approaches

```
var _clientlist = JObject.Parse(_jsonresp)["clients"].Children();
```

Which works, but I cannot get the values into a dataset/datable

```
_clientlist = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_jsonresp, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Fails :(

```
DataSet _dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(_jsonresp);
DataTable _clientlist = _dataset.Tables["clients"];
```

Similar process to above but same result

```
dynamic _d = JValue.Parse(_response);
JArray _jsonval = JArray.Parse(_d.clients) as JArray;
```

Fails :(

At which point I gave up.

Comment: Why avoid classes? you have two class with 3 properties each.. not a lot of work

Comment: Would you be alright deserializing into a object with two arrays of objects (one for clients, one for dossiers) instead of deserializing into datasets?

Comment: Why do you strictly need DataTable/DataSet?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: the first attempt does that: var _clientlist = JObject.Parse(_jsonresp)["clients"].Children(); Is it possible to get the object into a datatable?

Comment: @I4V: because I need to let the users apply search filters and datatables seem to work well for that. Unless if the can be done with objects??

Comment: @jure, yeah... unfortunately I have "hundreds" more to do :D

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer the question exactly because I personally don't see why you would want to deserialize into datasets when the json.NET model is more oriented around deserializing into objects. Here it is;

```
public class TheJson
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public client[] clients { get; set; }
    public dossier[] dossiers { get; set; }
}


public class client
{
     public string ClientID { get; set; }
     public string Fullname { get; set; }
     public bool Inactive { get; set; }
}

public class dossier
{
     public string CreateDate { get; set; }
     public string DossierName { get; set; }
}
```

With those definitions it's as simple as;

```
TheJson clientsAndDossiers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheJson>(_jsonresp);
```

Now with regard to your last comment, to apply search filters I would just use LINQ. Like for example if I want to get only active clients I could do;

```
List<client> activeClients = clientsAndDossiers.clients.Where(x => x.Inactive == false).ToList();
```

With regard your comment on this post, here is the LINQ implementation;

```
string inputString = MenuSearchBox.Text.ToString();
List<client> filtered = clientsAndDossiers.clients.Where(x => x.Fullname.Contains(inputString)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to allow users to apply filters to the data and so far the only method I have found is using datatables and _clientlist.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Fullname LIKE '%{0}%'", MenuSearchBox.Text.ToString());

Comment: @user1224125 that can also be easily done here with LINQ. I've edited with the equivalent LINQ query.

Comment: @user1224125 No problem. Anytime you're filtering with `LIKE '%{0}%'"` you would use `System.String.Contains(string input)` within a `Where` clause. If you're not familiar with the `x => x.Something` check out this msdn post on lambda expressions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx